# How to generate all permutations of an array in Julia?

Tags: julia

Given I have some array:

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
```

how can I generate all of its permutations? I am happy to write this by hand but would also be interested in a built in function which is performant.

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia, you can use the Combinatorics package to do the following:

```
julia> using Combinatorics

julia> b = permutations(a)
Combinatorics.Permutations{Vector{Int64}}([1, 2, 3], 3)

julia> for item in b
           print(item)
       end
[1, 2, 3][1, 3, 2][2, 1, 3][2, 3, 1][3, 1, 2][3, 2, 1]
```

You can read more about the permutations function in the [Combinatorics docs](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Combinatorics.jl).

Comment: How do you get permutations to return the indices of the permutation, such as to feed into the Combinatorics.jl levicivita function?